# Prevent app from becoming inactive when in lock screen

Tags: ios, swift

My app has a count down that plays a sound after the timer is finished and might start another timer. The timers are between 1-5 min long. The problem is, after I lock the screen on my phone, the app becomes inactive and the timer is not being continued.

I have this set in my `Info.plist` but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Can I prevent the app from becoming inactive while the timer is running?

Is "inactive" the right term for this? I know "running in background" is not the correct term because I don't need to run code while the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into Local Notifications (https://developer.apple.com/notifications/).

It will allow your users to be alerted when the timer is up   where they can either unlock their phone and relaunch your app, or dismiss the timer (which will also alert your app that the notification was acknowledged.

Apple has a great introductory video to get you started:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/

Comment: Thanks for answering, but please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) It is not good to only post links. They can change, we would like for your answer to be a record here.

Comment: @DCTID, the follow-on to the answer explains what local notifications do and why they might be a good solution to this question. It seems like a solid answer to me.